# Intel ethernet drivers for Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I've the following ethernet driver on my PC:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:df300000-df31ffff
```

Is there any driver for Ubuntu 17.04 available ?

I've tried to install the [Intel drivers](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005480.html) directly, but the installation failed 
with

```
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
/bin/sh: 1: [: -ge: unexpected operator
Makefile:181: *** *** Aborting the build. *** This driver is not 
supported on kernel versions older than 2.4.0.  Stop.
```

EDIT: It seems that recent Ubuntu versions already have that driver.
If I execute

```
sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e10
```

I get

```
[    0.845924] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.845924] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.916285] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate 
    (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.160768] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
[    1.202752] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -5
```

Comment: The driver *e1000e* is already included in recent Ubuntu versions. If it doesn't load and drive your device, something else is wrong. Please run this terminal command and edit your question to include the result: `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100`

Comment: ok, have added it...

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `uname -a`, `modinfo e1000e`, `cat /sys/module/e1000e/version`, and `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Ethernet`? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `dmesg`, we see:

```
e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
```

A Google search finds many examples of the error and subsequent failure to load the driver. What I will propose here is assumed to have some risk of failure. I have, however, found no reports of trying it and failing. If you have the slightest doubt after your own Google search, then I suggest that you contact the manufacturer of your laptop and ask for support.

If you wish to proceed, download [this file](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19186) to your desktop. You need the tar.gz file.

Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in the terminal, determine if yours is a 32- or 64-bit installation:

```
arch
```

If yours is a 64-bit installation, as I assume, the terminal will return `x86_64`. If so, we will use the 64-bit utility.

In the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/Preboot/APPS/BootUtil/Linux_x64/DRIVER
chmod +x bootutil64e
sudo ./bootutil64e -NIC=1 -DEFAULTCONFIG
```

Reboot and let us hear the result.

Reference on Super User: [How to repair the checksum of the non-volatile memory (NVM) Intel Ethernet Controller I219-V of an ASUS laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1104537/how-to-repair-the-checksum-of-the-non-volatile-memory-nvm-of-intel-ethernet-co)

Comment: works. thx a lot :)